# Tomcat not starting when running Heroku Java tutorial locally; "A child container failed during start" and cannot find webapp path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, heroku

I just created a new Heroku account and followed [the Heroku Java "Hello, World!" tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat) step-by-step. After copy-pasting the indicated files to the specified directories, the deployment worked exactly as described, with no problems, other than the test on the local side. The JSP and the servlet are both functioning properly on the live site. The point of all this is that I don't think there's anything wrong with the code itself.

Next, I wanted to set up my local dev environment so that I could use Eclipse and Maven with what was deployed to Heroku. I ran a `mvn package` through Eclipse and got a successful result. Then I tried running the app on `localhost` using `.\webapp.bat` and got

```
Jan 18, 2018 9:27:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/' and do not end with a '/'. The path [/] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to []
Jan 18, 2018 9:27:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat getWebappConfigFileFromJar
WARNING: Unable to determine web application context.xml D:\HerokuTutLocalInstance\target\bin\src\main\webapp
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\HerokuTutLocalInstance\target\bin\src\main\webapp (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getWebappConfigFileFromJar(Tomcat.java:1274)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getWebappConfigFile(Tomcat.java:1254)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:644)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:218)
        at launch.Main.main(Main.java:27)

configuring app with basedir: D:\HerokuTutLocalInstance\target\bin\.\src\main\webapp
Jan 18, 2018 9:27:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2018 9:27:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 18, 2018 9:27:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jan 18, 2018 9:27:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
Jan 18, 2018 9:27:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3e7e7728]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4860)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
[numerous similar errors snipped for length]
```

I thought maybe the problem had to do with the fact that Tomcat was looking for `src/main/webapp` in the wrong place. Changing the code to

```
String webappDirLocation = "../../src/main/webapp/";
```

doesn't help; the path part of the error just changes to

```
configuring app with basedir: D:\HerokuTutLocalInstance\target\bin\.\..\..\src\main\webapp
```

(The actual path is `D:\HerokuTutLocalInstance\src\main\webapp`.)

As far as I can tell, the numerous other posts on SO about similar-looking errors have different root causes. Why is this failing? Is it a Tomcat issue, or is that just a symptom of some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the script from the D:\HerokuTutLocalInstance directory and without your changes in the code, I mean using .\target\bin\webapp.bat

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried, before I changed the code. It's what created the error output in the first place. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I actually resolved this just now by taking a completely different approach, so I don't know what was going on but I also don't need an answer to this specific question anymore.